# How to read in and utilize column names with hyphens from data frame

Tags: r

I've been trying to create a simple function that will output beta estimates for MLR. The function takes in a file and converts it to a data frame, as well as the desired Y value from the data frame. The function works fine if I input a valid column name. However, I cannot seem to get it to work for a column name with a hyphen in it. For example, one of the column names in the "CLERICAL.xls" file below is "Y-Hours," and that's the Y variable I would like to choose. There are also other column names with hyphens that will represent X values contained in "~." which I assume will also cause a problem. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

I've tried using the str_replace_all() function to remedy the problem but I keep getting the same error message.

```
myinfluential = function(filename, Y) {
  library(readxl)
  df = read_excel(filename)
  names(df) = str_replace_all(names(df), c("-" = ""))
  f1 = paste(Y, "~.")
  f1 = formula(f1)
  y.lm = lm(f1, data = df)
  X = model.matrix(y.lm)
  Y = as.matrix(df[Y])
  beta.hat = solve(t(X)%*%X, tol = 1e-17)%*%t(X)%*%Y
  beta.hat
}
myinfluential("CLERICAL.xls", "Y-Hours")
```

Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'Hours' not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think one issue is that you are changing the column names by substituting the `-`, so when the function looks for the proper col, it can't find it? Maybe a simpler approach is to handle the naming convention and then change that throughout?

For instance if your input was `"Y-Hours"`, but cols had been renamed, such that now `Y-Hours` is `YHours` (after the substitution step), it can't find it. Thats the error message.

```
myinfluential = function(filename, Y) {
  library(readxl)
  df <- read_excel(filename)
  #names(df) = str_replace_all(names(df), c("-" = ""))
  names(df) <- gsub("\\-", "", names(df), perl = TRUE)
  # Here's the fix? 
  Y <- gsub("\\-", "", Y, perl = TRUE)
  # Now should match
  f1 = paste(Y, "~.")
  f1 = formula(f1)
  y.lm = lm(f1, data = df)
  X = model.matrix(y.lm)
  Y = as.matrix(df[Y])
  beta.hat = solve(t(X)%*%X, tol = 1e-17)%*%t(X)%*%Y
  beta.hat
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. This seemed to fix the problem

Comment: Glad to hear! if it worked feel free to accept the answer, or if you have any follow-ups just lemme know.